# Prove P is a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, vector-spaces

We have a population $p_j$ in year $j$ is governed by the following equation:

\begin{equation}
p_{j+1} = 2p_j + 3p_{j-1} + p_{j-2}
\end{equation}

I want to prove that the set of all sequences, **p** = $(p_0,p_1,p_2,...)$ for $j \geqslant 2$ is a vector space, denoted by **V**.

I started by taking 2 vectors, **u**, **v** such  that **u**= $p_{i+1}$ and **v** = $p_{k+1}$. I was trying to show that **u+v** $\in$ **V** but I'm not sure how to compute this to show that **u+v** $\in$ **V**.

Comment: Try to show that for any $i \ne k$ the quantity $q = p_i + p_k$ is expressible as $2p_j + 3p_{j - 1} + p_{j - 2}$

Answer (score 3):

Let $\bf{V}$ be the set of all sequences $\bf{p}=(p_0,p_1,\cdots)$. For $\bf{p,q}\in V$, then $\bf{p}=(p_0,p_1,\cdots)$, $\bf{q}=(q_0,q_1,\cdots)$ satisfy
$$ p_{j+1} = 2p_j + 3p_{j-1} + p_{j-2}, q_{j+1} = 2q_j + 3q_{j-1} + q_{j-2} $$
and hence
$$ p_{j+1}+q_{j+1} = 2(p_j+q_j) + 3(p_{j-1}+q_{j-1}) + (p_{j-2}+ q_{j-2}). $$
Namely $\bf{p+q}\in V$. You can check that the other properties of a vector space also hold.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When you have $p_{j+1} + q_{j+1}$, do you not have to then show that $p_j + q_j$, $p_{j-1}+q_{j-1}$, $p_{j-2}+q_{j-2}$ are all also in V so it would be kind of like an inductive proof?

Answer (score 2):

For two vectors $$u=(u_0,u_1, \cdots ) \in V$$ and $$v=(v_0, v_1, \cdots )\in V$$

We have $$u+v = (u_0+v_0,u_1+v_1, \cdots )=(w_0,w_1, \cdots)$$

Note that $$u_{n+1}+v_{n+1}=2(u_n+v_n)+3(u_{n-1}+v_{n-1})+(u_{n-2}+v_{n-2})$$
This gives $$w_{n+1}=2w_n+3w_{n-1}+w_{n-2}$$ which implies $$w=u+v \in V$$

Therefore, we have $V$ is a vector space.

Note that the zero vector is in $V$ and $V$ is closed in scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of looking at the problem:

Let $X$ denote the vector space of all sequences $x: \>{\mathbb N}_{\geq0}\to{\mathbb R}$. The *shift operator*
$$S: \quad X\to X,\qquad x=(x_0,x_1,x_2\ldots)\mapsto Sx:=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$$
is obviously a linear map, and so is
$$L:=S^3-2S^2-3S^1-S^0\ .$$
The set $V$ of all solutions $p\in X$ of the recursion $$p_{j+1}=2p_j+3p_{j-1}+p_{j-2}\qquad(j\geq2)$$is nothing else but the kernel of $L$, hence is a vector subspace of $X$.